# Pythonic way to iterate over multiple lists in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, iteration

This seems pretty simple, but I haven't found a way to do it.  I have three lists, a, b, and c.  I want to iterate over all of them as if their elements altogether form one big list.  I can think of a few ways to do this, but nothing very smooth or "pythonic".  I expected the splat operator to work:

```
for e in (*a, *b, *c):
   # do stuff with e
```

but that gives a syntax error.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

Comment: Actually, it would work in Python 3.5+. Still, you should use `itertools.chain`.

Comment: @vaultah. Nevermind. My mistake

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If they are all lists, all tuples, or all strings, then you can concatenate them:

```
for e in a + b + c:
```

For any combination of any iterables, including iterators like generators:

```
from itertools import chain

for e in chain(a, b, c):
```